# Cannot connect to update service, Windows update

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-10

Appreciate the help in advanced.

I am running into an issue when I try to use windows update on Windows 10 after the Anniversary update.

When I click check for updates, I get the following error message: "We couldnt connect to the update service. We'll try again later, or you can check now.  If it still doesnt work, make sure youre connected to the internet."

Couple things:

Lenovo Yoga laptop, 120 GB SSD, 4GB RAM. Windows 10 Pro

1. I am connected to the internet, tested and verified
2. I did a repair install of Windows 10
3. I put the laptop essentially into a DMZ mode. Opened all ports on firewall.
4. Ran windows update troubleshooter, no go
5. Found a bunch of articles online, ran the wsreset.exe

I am at wits end here, so I did a wireshark packet capture to see if its even hitting microsoft and vice versa.

I am getting a response back that looks fine, everything windows update is green.  However I am seeing it reference something called a disallowedcertstl.cab.  I have no idea if this is a cert issue or not.

I am out of options and I would prefer not to reformat this users pc.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a lot of issues with Windows Update on 10.

1.)Have you tried the PowerShell commands to purge the updates cache?[Purge Windows Updates](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-stuck-downloading-updates)

2.) I've fixed some update issues by using a different user profile. If it works then you know that it is a problem with your user profile. 
3.) Run a chkdsk to see if there are any problems. 
4.) Restore the machine.

Comment: You should quote and cite the relevant information from your link.

Comment: So #1 I did that.  I will have to try #2.